# Java - How to replace specific characters that are not contained in a word

Tags: java, replace, character

I am trying to replace 2 specific characters when i am returning a String result.

I want O character to be replaced with OR and A character to be replaced with AND only when it is not contained on a word.

Using

```
return test.replace("A","AND").replace("O","OR")
```

messes around with the rest of test return.

For example, when the output is supposed to be

> JOHN OR MARRY

i get

> JORHN OR MANDRRY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
return test.replace(" A "," AND ").replace(" O "," OR ")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I kinda feel stupid though for not thinking this trick. xD